# DB2 Error: Assignment of NULL value to not null column " " is not allowed?

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, insert, db2

I'm trying to do an insert on a table, and it's throwing this error. However, it isn't showing me the column affected.

Does anyone know whats going on here?

[image: DB2 Error]

Comment: Could you show the code? And something about the table schema?

Comment: I would guess you have not included all the columns in the insert statement and one/some of the missing columns are defined as not null. Suggest looking at DB Schema, Also listing the DB Schema and insert statement would be useful

Comment: I agree with @BruceMartin as to the probable cause.  One specific situation in which this can occur in DB2: if you have a table with an auto-generated key, then you create another table `LIKE` that table, the automatic generation is not copied over to the new table by default (but the `NOT NULL` property is). Thus an insert tries to assign null to the key that you assume is being auto-generated.

Comment: Good point Dan, its been a while since I have worked with DB2

Answer (score 1):

Somehow your app or SQL is sending `<NULL>` to a column that has been specified `"NOT NULL"`.

I just saw this in an app I am writing.  Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "PURCHASE" (
  "PURCHASE_NAME"   VARCHAR(150)    NOT NULL,
  "NOTIFY_FLAG" CHARACTER(1)    NOT NULL,
  "PURCHASE_AMOUNT" DECIMAL(9, 2)
)
```

Inserting in the following manner will generate the error you asked about:

```
INSERT INTO PURCHASE
(PURCHASE_NAME, NOTIFY_FLAG, PURCHASE_AMOUNT) 
VALUES 
('Lotus Organizer version 3.1', null, 12743.27);
```

Your screen shot shows that your DB client is not sending you the column information.  It should look something like this:

```
ERROR [23502] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0407N  Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL
column "TBSPACEID=15, TABLEID=11, COLNO=16" is not allowed.
```

To debug this, you will need to somehow catch the SQL your app is generating and run it through a more direct DB client, like TOAD (http://www.quest.com/database-management/).